# Match regular expression between delimiters

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file with several different lines. I'm looking for lines that contain(more or less) pattern like this:

```
\[.*<.*>.*\]
```

In other words, I want the lines that have `<something>` between []. Examples might be:

```
Line with [ <matching>|<pattern>]
A line <that> does[not]<match>[]
But [this[<should>]be matched] too
[match [me] <buddy>]
```

The only characters allowed between <> are alphanumeric characters and underscore.

I've tried both regexp above and its lazy version, but it didn't seem to work. What is the proper regexp?

Comment: How about `line [with <foo]bar>` or `line [with <foo]bar> baz]` or `a [b <c[d]e> f]`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've updated my question to answer yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `[`, `]` pairs are always matched and you don't criss-cross `[...]`s with `<...>`, and your `grep` supports the `-P` option (like GNU `grep` when built with PCRE support), you can do:

```
grep -P '>(?!((?:[^]]|\[(?1)\])*)$)'
```

That is, look for a `>` that is *not* followed by only matched `[...]` pairs. It uses PCREs' `(?1)` recursive matching mechanism.

Comment: Outstanding. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly, you could do it with `sed`:

```
sed  '
  h; # make a copy of the pristine line on the hold space
  :1
    /\[[^]]*<[^]]*>[^]]*]/{
      # found a [...<x>...]
      g; # retrieve our saved copy and branch off
      b
    }
    s/\[\([^]]*\)]/\1/g; # remove inner [...]s
    # and loop if that s command was successful
  t1
  # no [...] left to remove, discard this line.
  d'
```

That is, remove pairs of `[...]` starting from the inner ones until you find a `<...>` within a pair.

(on Solaris or very old systems, remove the comments as Solaris sed only allows comments at the start of the lines).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
grep -P '\[[^.\]]*<.*>[^.\[]*\]' filename
```

In other words we match a pair of [ and ] with a pair of < and > in between with the following constraints:

1. between [] must not be closing and opening bracket accordingly before and after the <> pair "[^.\]]*".
2. inside <> must be at least one character.

This solution is also much faster than the regex with lazy quantifiers.

Comment: Unfortunately fails for [a [b] <c>]

Answer (score 0):

This pattern with lazy matching (needing -P AFAIU) works for me:

```
grep -P '\[[^\]]*?<.*>.*?\]'
```

Comment: Unfortunately fails for [a [b] <c>]

Comment: True, I only tested your tests. I'll update in case I find a solution.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: Actually Stephane did great work. You may want to check this out.